# Google scripts timestamp time zone isn't working

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I am trying to set a timestamp from google scripts to google sheets,
The time zone isn't correct and I am trying to change it,
Yet the change is not making any difference with the result,
What can be the reason?

Image for the code and result attached.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpZNb.png)

Comment: Please do not include code in an image. [Use a stack snippet instead.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: I think you need to remove the space beween "GMT" and "+" (or "-"). It should `GMT+1`, `GMT-3`, etc

Comment: Hi there @סערוינברג! Please, take this opportunity to learn [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) questions, how can you [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186) and share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with us so we can help you better. Then, please share the code with us so we can take a look. Also, did the solution proposed by @YuriKhristich work in your scenario?

Comment: Thank you! The space was the problem and now its working :)